# What is Gavin Darklighter shooting at in the art on the X-Wing 2.0 card?

Tags: star-wars

On the card for Gavin Darklighter in the X-Wing Miniatures Game (second edition), we see Gavin Darklighter in his E-Wing shooting at something that looks to me a lot like just regular aircraft as we know it in real life. What ship from *Star Wars* is that?

[image: Gavin Darklighter E-Wing Pilot Card]

Source: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/xwing-miniatures-second-edition/images/2/2c/Gavin_Darklighter_Pilot_Card.png/revision/latest?cb=20180717190354

Comment: He is shooting at a spaceship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [*Orbital jumper*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Orbital_jumper):

[image]

> The orbital jumper was a light shuttle produced by Poranji. Not
> hyperspace-capable, orbital jumpers were popular on Core Worlds such
> as Coruscant for travel in near-planetary space. Vessels of this type
> were used by high-ranking military and government officers for travel
> on short notice during the Black Fleet Crisis.

[image]
An E-wing fighter fires on a pair of orbital jumpers.

Comment: So I was right!

Comment: @Valorum indeed =)

Comment: Those pictures clearly do not match.  Compare the positioning of the central fin and the under-wing engines, for example.

Comment: @Buzz agree. Still that could be different models or just some small mistake from the side of the artist, who drew those pictures.